# Check if a DOM element is selected/highlighted by user

Tags: javascript

Is it possible in JavaScript to know if the text of a specified DOM element is selected/highlighted by the user?
I don't want to get the selected text (like in [Get the Highlighted/Selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text)), but just know if the element is selected/highlighted.

Comment: Y​e​s​,​ ​i​t is.

Comment: With [`getSelection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/getSelection) and [`containsNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/containsNode).

Comment: containsNode is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks.